# Azure Container Instance udp/tcp

Tags: azure, tcp, udp, containers, instance

I try to expose two ports for grafana and graphite 80 and 8125.
I receive an error when I try open two ports :

```
"error": {
"code": "MixedProtocolsNotSupported",
"message": "Mixed protocols are found in container group 'test'. A container group can have either protocol TCP or UDP, but can't have both."
```

this is from my template

```
"osType": "Linux",
            "ipAddress": {
                "type": "Public",
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "protocol": "tcp",
                        "port": "80"
                    },
                    {
                        "protocol": "udp",
                        "port": "8125"
                    }
                ]
             }
```

Maybe someone has workaround for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today ACI supports one protocol per IP address. To work around this you can deploy a separate containerGroup for TCP and one for UDP.

Comment: is this still an issue?

Comment: Did this get fixed? I am trying to host an Unreal Engine game server which utilizes 7777 on tcp/udp.  Please help!!!